# What is Windows 7's Fault Tolerant Heap?

Tags: windows-7, fault-tolerant-heap

I'd like some technical information on how it works, and how I can disable or enumerate the Fault Tolerant Heap shims that are associated with processes that crash frequently.  Is there a heuristic of some sort that Windows 7 uses to decide when to apply an FTH shim?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fault Tolerant Heap is a layer over the heap that defends against common heap errors, such as heap overruns, double frees,  and so on.  To my knowledge, there is only one FTH shim - not multiple for each mitigation.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744764(VS.85).aspx describes how you can monitor if FTH is being enabled for an application via the event log.

I don't believe MS has published the exact heuristic that will enable the FTH, but yes, there is a heuristic.

Comment: Today I also noticed a debug output string that shows FTH is being enabled for a process I was debugging:

OutputDebugString FTH: (9556): *** Fault tolerant heap shim applied to current process. This is usually due to previous crashes. ***

Comment: Mark Russinovich talked about this at PDC 2010. The problem is that I don't remember which talk it was part 1 or part 2:
http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/PDC/PDC10?sort=sequential&direction=desc&term=&s=Mark%2BRussinovich