# How to get back plain old "Segmentation fault" message in windows?

Tags: windows, gcc, segmentation-fault, mingw

I'm facing a strange behaviour in my windows 10 development environment.

I compile the following code (mingv gcc-8.1.0)

```
int main(){
    char* x = nullptr;
    std::cout<<*x<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this program in a cmd or powershell window, it outputs a blank line, waits for a bunch of seconds and then returns to prompt.

I'd love to have it print "segmentation fault" and exit immediately, as god intended.

If I run the program in GDB the error is shown correctly (`Thread 1 received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.`).

Could someone please explain why it does this and if there is a way to obtain the desired behaviour?

Related: [Why won't my code segfault on Windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629551/why-wont-my-code-segfault-on-windows-7)

Comment: *I'd love to have it print "segmentation fault" and exit immediately, as god intended.* Welcome to undefined behavior land, the place god forgot about.

Comment: There are some nasal demons though.

Comment: Why the C tag? This is not C.

Comment: @klutt The example code is C++, but the problem is not C++ specific. I removed both C and C++ tags.

Comment: If you want a `SIGSEGV`, there's `raise(SIGSEGV)`. If you want to print "Segmentation fault.", try `std::cerr << "Segmentation fault.\n";`. If you want Linux, you can even find it in the Windows Store these days.

Comment: It is not, in general, reasonable to rely on null pointer dereferences in C or C++ to produce any specific behavior, including segfaults.  This is the meaning of the "undefined" in "undefined behavior".

Comment: @JohnBollinger thank you for your answer. I understand, but in this specific case the compiler is generating the illegal access as expected, as we can see through the debugger; nasal daemons are not there: the segfault IS generated, just not displayed. My question is more about "why is the error hidden when I do not use a debugger? Can I change that? How? What is happening in those seconds before the prompt comes back?".

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem and found this question when looking for an answer.

Short version, I couldn't come up with a solution by default. Instead I was able to use [signal](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html) to process the SIGSEGV and print my own message. It's not great, but it's enough to notice the error and debug it.

```
#include <signal.h>

void segvHandler( int s ) 
{
  printf( "Segmentation Fault\n" );
  exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}

....

// at the start of main
  signal( SIGSEGV, segvHandler );
```

Longer answer:
I'm working in an msys environment on win10.  Compiling a test application in a Command Prompt windows using the default gcc produces no fault  message when run in a command prompt but does produce a message when run in a an msys shell or in GDB.

```
> C:\msys64\mingw32\bin\gcc.exe --version
gcc.exe (Rev3, Built by MSYS2 project) 12.1.0
```

The same source compiled in an msys shell using the default gcc produces an fault message when run in the msys shell, gdb, and a Command Prompt window.

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 11.3.0
```